# VBA problems with selecting specific rows/cells from the filtered range

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a problem selecting specific cells after applying filters to the data in one of the tabs. Basically, in „issues” tab I have some set of data. Firstly, I need to apply three different filters (done via „AutoFilter”), then (let's say that there are just three rows left, these are rows 780, 1716 and 4286) I want to address the first visible row (apart from the first row with headers).

```vb
dim rowNumber as Long
rowNumber = issues.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(2).Row
```

It works and gives me the `rowNumber = 780`, which is correct.

But when I want to select the second visible row and change offset to 2 - nothing changes. Actually it will not change unless I set offset to a number which is at least 780 (then it returns the number equal to the second visible row).

I thought about overcoming this by copying the visible range to some next tab, there I would have just three consecutive rows (1, 2, and 3, excluding headers), but I am not able to copy the range neither.

```vb
dim filteredRange as Range
filteredRange = issues.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

`filteredRange.copy destination:=sheet2.Range("A2")` does not work and gives me `sheet2.Range("A2") = <Object variable or With block variable not set>`.

```
Do you know what might be the reason?
```

Comment: Your copy/paste line should work. But it appears you **typed** it in and did not **copy/paste** from your actual code. Perhaps you have a typo.  Your other approach requires knowing that the Range object returned by `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` consists of different `Areas` representing each group of contiguous cells that are returned, and you are not accounting for that.

Comment: sorry, I have just started learning vba recently. could you please tell me how to account for that and overcome the issue?

Comment: It's simpler to use the copy/paste method. Figure out why that's not working.

Comment: Why don't you share a screenshot of your data and the complete relevant code so we could explain exactly what is going on? I mean we don't know if you are filtering one or more columns. We don't know whether a worksheet with the code name `sheet2` exists. You're using the shortcut `(2)` where we cannot know if this refers to the next cell, row, area, or what? Most importantly, what is the final goal of your excursion? Do you want to copy or delete or something else? You most certainly don't want to select. Please add additional information to your post. BTW, it is `Set filteredRange = ...`.

Comment: As VBasic said, it's `Set filteredRange = ` but even then, using `Set filteredRange = issues.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` includes the header. If you don't want the header, you'll have to specify the range a bit more, i.e. `Set filteredRange = issues.Range("A1:I" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` or something similar with `lRow = issues.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (in my test the A-column wasn't populated completely so I used the B-column).

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in Ron's now-deleted answer...

If you run `SpecialCells` you often get back a multi-area range: you can't reliably index into that using `filteredRange(row, column)`, because your row/column are always applied to the *first area* (and can extend beyond that area).  - if there were two rows (lets's say 5 and 10) then `filteredRange(2, 1).Row` would be 6 not 10.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Union(Rows(5), Rows(10))
    
    Debug.Print rng.Cells(1, 1).Row    '5 - only works reliably for first cell
    
    Debug.Print rng.Cells(2, 1).Row    '6!
    Debug.Print rng.Rows(2).Row        '6!
    
    'for each is a reliable way to loop over the range...
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        Debug.Print rw.Row             '5 and 10
    Next rw
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing offsetCount (oCt) you are moving the area.
By changing cellCount (cCt) you are walking through the different cells. (not reliable as stated by Tim Williams).

```
debug.print issues.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(oCt).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(cCt)
```

With your code you either move the area or walk through the individual cells (and not rows).

The below lines count the number of visible cells, display the individual visible cell addresses, their row number and their value and finally the cells of the first column and their row numbers are shown:

```
Sub display_filtered_range()
    Dim cellCount As Long
    cellCount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    Debug.Print "CellCount: " & cellCount

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print myCell.Address & " Row: " & myCell.Row & " Value: " & myCell.Value
        lastRow = myCell.Row
    Next myCell
      
    Dim firstCol As Long
    Debug.Print "Only first column of filtered range:"
    firstCol = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Column
    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, firstCol), Cells(lastRow, firstCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print myCell.Address & " Row: " & myCell.Row & " Value: " & myCell.Value
    Next myCell
End Sub
```